# CSS prevent from resizing at a point?

Tags: html, css, web

Hi all I am making a website and I am trying to make the width of the object to not overscale, i.e I have a body tag and I set the page width to 60% and that is fine and now I am trying to set min width of xx% so the elements will not go over each other and I am trying to stop the browser from going over that xx% and show all content on the page.

I hope someone understands what i am trying to do and will help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `max-width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   .example{
       max-width: 60%;
    }

    .example{
   min-width:60%;
    }
```

You mean max-width and min-width ?

```
.wrapper {
  min-width: 50em; /* Overrides max-width */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20em; /* Will be AT MOST 20em wide */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you fro reply, I am trying to make the whole website from resizing too much i.e I want the max width of the site to be 70% and min 50% however when I apply that code in my body class it just sets the max width and ignores the min.

Comment: The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.

The min-width property is used to set the minimum width of an element.


I updated answer with a small example

Comment: Thank You soo much, that is exactly what I needed to have. One day I will be as good :) Thanks again.